# JAVA combobox blank spaces

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I got a combobox filled with items.

Whenever I delete one of the items, the value is deleted but not the 
blank space inside the combobox?

How do i fix this?

this is javafx :)

If i would have 10 items inside my combobox and delete them all I would have 10 blank spaces ..

```
 @FXML
public void toevoegenPloeg(ActionEvent event) throws ApplicationException, DBException {

    //verbinding met transactielaag
    PloegTrans pt = new PloegTrans();

    lblCorrect.setText("");
    lblError.setText("");

    //kijken of er een niveau geselecteerd is (must)
    if(cboNiveau.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null){
        taPloegen.setVisible(true);
        //niveau ophalen uit combobox
        String niveau = cboNiveau.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().name();

        //verbinding met db klasses
        PloegDB pdb = new PloegDB();
        PersoonDB pb = new PersoonDB();

        //ploegnaam berekenen
        Integer aantal = pdb.zoekAantalPloegenPerNiveau(niveau);

        //als aantal groter is dan " Z " dan error geven
        if (aantal+1 < 27) {
            String ploegnaam = niveau + getLetter(aantal+1);;
            try{

                //indien geen trainer geselectteerd dan ploeg maken zonder trainer
                if(cboTrainer.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) {

                    //gegevens setten
                    PloegBag pr = new PloegBag();
                    pr.setNaam(ploegnaam);
                    pr.setNiveau(niveau);
                    int ploegID = pt.toevoegenPloegZonderTrainer(pr);

                    pr.setId(ploegID);

                    lblCorrect.setText("ploeg werd aangemaakt");

                    //toevoegen gegevens en combobox op leeg zetten
                    taPloegen.getItems().add(pr);
                    cboNiveau.getSelectionModel().select(null);
                    iniTabel();
                }

                // anders gaan we een ploeg maken met een trainer
                else {
                    //trainerid berkenenen
                    Integer trainerId =  cboTrainer.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId();

                    PloegBag pr = new PloegBag();
                    PersoonBag pa = cboTrainer.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

                    //setters voor het persoonbag
                    pr.setNaam(ploegnaam);
                    pr.setNiveau(niveau);
                    pr.setTrainer_id(trainerId);

                    int ploegID = pt.toevoegenPloeg(pr);
                    pr.setId(ploegID);

                    lblCorrect.setText("Ploeg werd aangemaakt");

                    //toevoegen aan tableview en comboboxes leegmaken
                    taPloegen.getItems().add(pr);
                    cboNiveau.getSelectionModel().select(null);
                    cboTrainer.getSelectionModel().select(null);

                    //trainer heeft nu een ploeg dus erwijderen wehem uit de combobox
                    cboTrainer.getItems().remove(pa);
                    iniTabel();
                }
            } catch (DBException ae){
                lblError.setText("Onherstelbare fout: " + ae.getMessage());
            }
             catch (ApplicationException ae){
                lblError.setText(ae.getMessage());
            }
        } else { 
            lblError.setText("Ploegenniveau zit vol");
        }
    } else {
        lblError.setText("Geen niveau geselecteerd");
    }
}


 private void iniComboTrainer(){
    PersoonDB pdb = new PersoonDB();

    try{
        ArrayList<PersoonBag> persoonlijst = pdb.zoekAlleOpenTrainers();
        for(PersoonBag pb : persoonlijst){
            cboTrainer.getItems().add(pb);
        }
    } catch (ApplicationException ae) {
        lblError.setText(ae.getMessage());
    } catch (DBException ae) {
        lblError.setText("onherstelbare fout: " + ae.getMessage());
    }
}
```

EDIT: i still have'nt found the issue.. i tried all options.. here's what I mean when the item is deleted the blank space still exists.[image: combobox blank space]

**edit: whenever i swap to another page and go back the blank spaces are gone.. but not when i'm on the same page**

Comment: Show us the code where you delete it, a fast response is because you forgot to delete it from the model, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What's select( null) supposed to do? Use clearSelection().

Comment: to clear the selection, i deleted it

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: ohh .. very old question ;) Might have been a bug at that time (though not aware of anything near such a behavior), or an application error .. no way to tell without a runnable example

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing somethhing like this right after you remove the item.

```
comboBox.setVisibleRowCount(comboBox.getVisibleRowCount()-1);`
```

Answer (score 0):

make clear() on items list and fill it with new list.

Example:
Combo.getItems().clear();
Combo.getItems() .addAll(newItemList);

Comment: one hacking guess is as good or as bad as the other - without details, can't do more than wild guessing, can we :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).